# Retrieving values from a <p> with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

I'm browsing a web page with HtmlUnit to get the text (a code) inside a span. This code is generated every time I get to the page after I've logged in. This is an example of how the HTML looks:

```
<div id="Main" class="" role="main">
    <p>Your code for this session:</p>
    <p style="align: center; text-align: center;">
        <span>XXX-XXX-XXX</span>
    </p>
</div><!--end Main-->
```

I want to get the code (this thing--> **XXX-XXX-XXX**).

I have tried the following:

```
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://the_url");
final HtmlDivision div = page.getHtmlElementById("Main");
```

However, when I print the div's contents, it prints the text from the `<a>` tags.

I'm not using `getByXPath("//div[@class='someclass']//p");` because the div class is empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your question really about how to locate the span containing XXX-XXX-XXX (using XPath or otherwise)? Does the <div id="main"> wrap the HTML you've posted? It might be worth editing the question to include a more complete example of the HTML you're dealing with.

Comment: @Rowan yes to both questions, i made a mistake when formatting the html code, so it's now the complete html code now

Comment: Your question mentions `<a>` tags as well (although that wasn't visible until I went to edit the question) - perhaps they should be in your HTML example too?

Comment: yes, i forgot that i have to format those too XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have HTMLUnit to hand, but the XPath query `"//*[@id='Main']/p/span"` should get you the `span` element (if the HTML you're dealing with is as in your example). You should then be able to get the text from that element to find your XXX-XXX-XXX code.

It's been a long while since I used HTMLUnit, but from [the docs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getTextContent()), it looks like the full code you'd want would be something like:

```
String code = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id='Main']/p/span").getTextContent();
```